# Inheritance References not working correctly

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

When running the following code, which involves changing the value of a int via a method of a class called B, which inherits from a templated class A, the value of the int doesn't change, and I cannot understand why, I have tested both of these with clang trunk and gcc trunk:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    A(T& a_num_) : a_num(a_num_) {}

    T& a_num;
};

struct B : public A<int>
{
    template<typename... Args>
    B(Args... args) : A<int>(args...) {}

    void do_something()
    {
        a_num = 1634;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int num = 4;

    B b {num};
    b.do_something();

    std::cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to get 1634 printed, but instead 4 prints.

I have narrowed the error to the constructor of B, because if I change the constructor of B to be:

```
B(int& x) : A<int>(x) {}
```

then the correct value appears, but the current constructor should also be receiving an int, because when I type:

```
B b {num};
```

Then it should choose Args = [int&], because that's the only way to satisfy A's constructor, which takes a T&, so what is happening here? What is a_num in this case? Just a garbage reference that doesn't reference anything, or possibly a temporary object?

I've also tried to rewrite the do_something function as

```
A<int>::a_num = 1634
```

but it still doesn't manage to change it.

I've also noticed that declaring b as:

```
B b {6};
```

Also works, although there's no way 6, which is a pr-value, could bind to a l-value reference.

So my question here is why does B's constructor choose Args = [int] instead of Args = [int&] and how can it do this when it then passes that Args to a constructor that takes a T&?

Comment: Template argument deduction is similar to predicting the future by examining sheep entrails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change B's constructor to take `Args` as a reference `Args&...`:

```
template<typename... Args>
B(Args&... args) : A<int>(args...) {}
```

Now your code will print `1634` as you originally wanted.

### Confirming the memory addresses

If you want to confirm that those variables point to the same memory address, you can do:

```
std::cout << &num << '\n';
std::cout << &b.a_num << '\n';
```

This prints the same memory address. For example:

```
0x7fff5508cac8
0x7fff5508cac8
```

### Using pointers

Since the idea is to make both `num` and `A::a_num` point to the same memory address, it is worth mentioning a solution that uses pointers. In that case, you don't have to change B's constructor, but you have to change `A::a_num` to be a `T*`.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    A(T* a_num_) : a_num(a_num_) {}

    T* a_num;
};

struct B : public A<int>
{
    template<typename... Args>
    B(Args... args) : A<int>(args...) {}

    void do_something() {
        *a_num = 1634;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int num = 4;

    B b {&num};
    b.do_something();

    std::cout << num;
}
```

This code also prints `1634` as you originally wanted.

**Edit**: I should remember that this code is bad practice and should never be recommended for production use. The memory address of local variables should never be passed around since they are only valid while the scope exists in the stack. We can implement much better code by using smart pointers or simply by copying the values instead of reusing their memory addresses.

Comment: Thanks @MilesBudnek, you are right. I have simplified the `main()` function, so now there is no uninitialized pointer. But on the other side, it now passes the address of the local `num` variable to the constructor, which would be a crazy piece of code in real life (never recommended).

Comment: what is the "point" of the pointer example? This is worse than the original code.

Comment: @MM The OP was trying to make both `num` and `A::a_num` have the same memory address so that when you modify the `A::a_num` field, you also modify the `num` variable that lives in the `main()` scope. Using pointers is an alternative so I just decided to mention it. But I do agree that such code is pure bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've marked it as accepted although I was wondering if you could also explain with `Args...` can't deduce to a reference since not doing so (this is to say by rewriting `Args...` as `int`) would evoke a warning from most compilers: `warning: binding reference member 'a_num' to stack allocated parameter 'a_num_'`, is this just a slight overlook or is there a reason to do so?

Comment: Since `Args...` is not explicitly declared as a reference or pointer, the compiler will only try to deduce it as a pass-by-value situation. In other words, if the _type_ of the parameter is neither a pointer nor a reference, the _param_ (`Args...` in this case) will be a copy of whatever is passed in.

Answer (score 4):

The only time a template type parameter will be deduced to be a reference type is when you declare the corresponding function parameter to be `T&&` and pass an lvalue to the function.

That means in this case `Args` is deduced to be `{int}`.  After `B`'s constructor is instantiated, it looks like this:

```
B(int arg) : A<int>(arg) {}
```

This is perfectly valid, because `arg` is an lvalue, and so the `a_num_` parameter to `A`'s constructor can bind to it.  You then copy that reference to the `A`'s `a_num` member and then the function parameter it's bound to goes out of scope and `a_num` becomes a dangling reference.  The behavior when you attempt to assign through `a_num` is therefore undefined.

---

If you want `B`'s constructor to take its arguments by reference, then you need to define the argument's type to be a reference:

```
tmeplate <typename... Args>
B(Args&... args) : A<int>(args) {}
```

If you do that then `b.a_num` will be a reference to the `num` you defined in `main` and everything will work like you expect.

Comment: When you say that `B(int arg) : A<int>(arg) {}` is valid, when I try it on a compiler it gives the following warning: `warning: binding reference member 'a_num' to stack allocated parameter 'a_num_'` and so because it's issuing a warning, shouldn't it realize that using {int&} is more correct than using {int}?

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, disregard that comment, it does in fact not give a warning, I was testing the wrong thing, but shouldn't it detect that arg is stack allocated and give a warning?